# iOS 3.2 MPMoviePlayerViewController and Three 20's TTNavigator

Tags: ipad, three20, mpmovieplayercontroller

I tried running my working 3.1.x application on 3.2 and realized that 
the MPPlayerController framework had changed.

After doing some research the common method should be to add the 
MPMoviePlayerViewController's view as a subview.

Somehow this does not work for me ...

I have TTTableViewController with items such as :

```
 [TTTableSubtitleItem itemWithText:@"Text" subtitle:@"subtitle" imageURL:@"bundle://1.jpg" defaultImage:nil URL:@"tt://videos/0" accessoryURL:nil],
```

This is then mapped:

```
 [map from:@"tt://videos/(playMovieAtIndex:)" toViewController: [VideoViewController class]];
```

and the VideoViewController finally plays the movie:

```
 MPMoviePlayerViewController* controller = 
 [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:theURL]; 

if (controller) 
    {

            self.mp = controller; 

            self.mp.moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen; 
            self.mp.moviePlayer.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFit; 
            self.mp.moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile; 
            [controller release]; 
            [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:self.mp]; 
            [self.mp.moviePlayer play]; 
    }
```

But only audio is played, and the MoviePlayer view is not actually 
shown. 
What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  My quick work-around was to not use:

`[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:self.mp];`

But instead, add the subview to the parent controller manually:

`[self.view addSubview:self.mp.view];`

Comment: Actually that did not work either. 
I found the solution : Adding the MPMoviePlayerViewController to  [TTNavigator visibleViewController] worked.